# Creating a simple Chrome extension that removes text select and right click protection?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to make a very simple Chrome extension that simply removes any text selection and/or right click protection on web pages. Unfortunately, the content script makes no changes to the web page.

My content script consists of:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].oncontextmenu = null;
    elements[i].onselectstart = null;
}
```

However, when I use this block of code in my content script:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i]);
}
```

All of the elements are printed, which means that the variable is definitely being created. Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried waiting until the DOM content has loaded? For example, if the code is read as soon as the browser initalises a tab, there is a chance the elements of the page have not generated their tokens and been loaded into the DOM. My suggestion is to do the following.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    for (var i = 0, items = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'); i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log(items[i]);

    };
}, false
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, nothing shows up in the console when using your code. Also, I don't think the issue is with the DOM content not loading, as my second example (using console.log) works. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is your extension able to get elements from the target page? For example you're able to to get elements from the console inline command with development tools, but is it possible that the script is "blind" to them?

Comment: I might have not explained the question clearly: when I use the second example in the content script instead of the first block of code, all of the elements are printed, which means that the script is definitely being injected into the page. I only run into issues when trying to use `oncontextmenu` and `onselectstart`. What other way can I use those events?

Comment: What if you tried using the `addEventListener` method? It may not alter the result too much but perhaps `elements[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) { e = null; });`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. I'll keep looking around for more possible solutions, but thanks for the help nonetheless.

Comment: @kootling - Try using removeEventListener to remove all of the event handlers on the elements.